# Is evaluating a pointer that points to beyond an object's storage undefined?

Tags: c, pointers, c11

Consider the snippet of code:

```
int main(void)
{
   int i = 42;
   int *p = &i;

   ++p; // Is this pointer evaluation undefined?
   *p = 5; // How about this?

   return 0;
}
```

The evaluation of the pointer in `++p` is ill-formed?

The C standard  (C11, 6.5.6) allows evaluating a pointer to one past end of an *array* object? Is this applicable to non array objects as well?

Comment: `p++` is OK, but `p++` again after that would cause UB. One beyond the end is a special case

Comment: @MattMcNabb I think changing it to `++p` would make it clearer. I'll edit.

Comment: I have received 2 downvotes so far. If there's something wrong with the question, please let me know and I'll improve it.

Comment: `*p` is dereferencing an invalid pointer, so yes, it's behaviour is undefined regardless. The paragraph of the C standard you refer to deals with expressions that evaluate to a pointer that is out of bonds, it does not mention dereferencing that pointer, because that's always bad

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem No. It does say about dereferencing an out of bounds pointer: **If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is evaluated.**

Comment: @3u3: I was referring to the bit you posted here. Either way: why did you post the question, than? Doesn't that answer your question? `*p = 5;` uses the invalid pointer as an operand of the `*` operator. Even if `i` were `int i[1] = {1};`, and `p = &i[0];`, the standard clearly states that `*p = 5;` is not allowed

Comment: @3u3: Sure it is (didn't notice you posted the answer, too). I just find it strange to ask a question containing an incomplete paragraph of the standard, and then answer it by, basically, posting the rest of the same paragraph. Posting a question with an answer is fine, but this one feels a bit off, because it's not _really_ about a specific coding problem, but more about the standard... either way, that's just my opinion

Comment: @3u3: the paragraph from the C standard you quoted in this question is incomplete. The full text **is** the answer, basically this question seems to be _"does this (`*p = 5;`) invoke UB, because the standard says [partial quote]"_, to which you posted the answer: _"Yes, because C11 6.5.6 reads [full quote, including the bit about the unary `*` operator]"_ If you were to post the full 6.5.6 paragraph as oart if the question, it wouldn't have been a question anymore, but a blog post explaining why `p++;` is legal, but `*p` is not

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. `++p` in the above program is well-defined. But `*p=5;` leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

The C standard states

*C11 draft, 6.5.6  Additive operators, p7*

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is
>   not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first
>   element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its
>   element type.

Which allows us to consider `int i` as `int i[1];` when pointer arithmetic is performed on the object `i` and 6.5.6, p8 follows:

> [..]If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of
>   the same array object, or one past the last element of the array
>   object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined. If the result points one past the last element
>   of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary `*`
>   operator that is evaluated.

So the evaluation of `&i+1` is well-defined in C whether or not `i` is an array of object. However, the de-referencing it is undefined:

```
int i = 9;
int *p = &i + 1; // Only pointer evaluation done here. Well-defined.
int x = *(p-1); // well defined. p-1 is should be equal to &i as required by 6.5.6, p8
*p = 42; // ill-formed.

int arr[5];
int *q = arr+5; // well-defined. Evaluating one past the end of an array.
*q = 42; //This is undefined.
```

However, this is applicable only for the one-past-end of the array. For example, the second increment in the following is undefined:

```
int i = 9;
int *p = &i;

++p; // This is OK. Evaluation is allowed.
*p = 5; // This is undefined. Not allowed to de-reference the pointer one past the end.
++p; // This is undefined. `p` now points to two past the end of the object after increment.
*p = 5; // This is undefined.
```

Comment: Nice answer. Is this the same for C++?

Comment: I haven't checked C++ standards. But I think it's the same to my knowledge.

Comment: @CoolGuy basically, yes. C++11 doesn't strictly say that `*p = 5` is undefined, if `p` is known to hold the address of another object, but I think C++14 rules that out again

Comment: So the basic point is that if the object pointed to is at the end of memory, then pointing beyond it will not point to address 0x00000... _and thus_ that apparently the object is placed at most at end-of-memory - 1.